# matrix enlargement in vhdl

Tags: matrix, vhdl

I have a matrix (size n x m) in matlab. And I want to enlarge the matrix size to n+2x, m+2y) by adding zeros around the original n x m matrix.

Example:
original 2x2 matrix
1 2
3 4

New 4x4 matrix [0 0 0 0; 0 1 2 0; 0 3 4 0; 0 0 0 0]
0 0 0 0
0 1 2 0
0 3 4 0
0 0 0 0

How can I do it in vhdl?

Answer (score 0):

```vhdl
type matrix is array(natural range <>, natural range <>) of natural;
signal matrix2x2 : matrix(0 to 1, 0 to 1);
signal matrix6x4 : matrix(0 to 5, 0 to 3);

function expand_matrix(m : matrix; x : natural; y : natural) return matrix is
  constant ROWS : natural := m'length(1) + 2 * y;
  constant COLS : natural := m'length(2) + 2 * x;

  variable mx : matrix(0 to ROWS-1, 0 to COLS-1) := (others => (others => 0));

begin

  for r in y to y + m'length(1) - 1 loop
    for c in x to x + m'length(2) - 1 loop
      mx(r, c) := m(r-y, c-x);
    end loop;
  end loop;

  return mx;
end function;

begin

matrix2x2 <= ((1, 2), (3, 4));

matrix6x4 <= expand_matrix(matrix2x2, 1, 2);
```

For simplicity I made the matrix type a 2D array of natural. If you intend to eventually synthesize this you will be better off changing to a more constrained integer type or use the signed/unsigned vector types with only the number of bits you need.